# Handling SIGPIPE error in snakemake

Tags: snakemake, sigpipe

The following snakemake script:

```
rule all:
    input:
        'test.done'

rule pipe:
   output:
       'test.done'
   shell:
        """
        seq 1 10000 | head > test.done
        """
```

fails with the following error:

```
snakemake -s test.snake

Provided cores: 1
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job counts:
    count   jobs
    1   all
    1   pipe
    2

rule pipe:
    output: test.done
    jobid: 1

Error in job pipe while creating output file test.done.
RuleException:
CalledProcessError in line 9 of /Users/db291g/Tritume/test.snake:
Command '
        seq 1 10000 | head > test.done
        ' returned non-zero exit status 141.
  File "/Users/db291g/Tritume/test.snake", line 9, in __rule_pipe
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 55, in run
Removing output files of failed job pipe since they might be corrupted:
test.done
Will exit after finishing currently running jobs.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

The explanation *returned non-zero exit status 141* seems to say that snakemake has caught the SIGPIPE fail sent by `head`. I guess strictly speaking snakemake is doing the right thing in catching the fail, but I wonder if it would be possible to ignore some types of errors like this one. I have a snakemake script using the `head` command and I'm trying to find a workaround this error.

Comment: Yes, Snakemake sets pipefail by default, because in most cases this is people implicitly expect. You can always deactivate it for specific commands by prepending `set +o pipefail; ` to the shell command.

Comment: Thank you! If you post that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, Snakemake sets pipefail by default, because in most cases this is what people implicitly expect. You can always deactivate it for specific commands by prepending `set +o pipefail;` to the shell command.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe just a note of warning... `set +o pipefail` should be used with care since it will make succeed also a broken command like this `seq 1 10000 | FooBar | head > {output}`

Comment: Exactly, that is why Snakemake enables pipefail by default.

Comment: I just use alternatives `awk 'NR<=10'` or ` sed -n '1,10p'` instead of `head` in order to avoid issues mentioned by @dariober.

Answer (score 4):

A somehow clunky solution is to append `|| true` to the script. This will make the command always exit cleanly, which is not acceptable. To check whether the script actually succeded you can query the array variable `${PIPESTATUS[@]}` to ensure it contains the expected exit codes:

This script is ok:

```
seq 1 10000 | head | grep 1 > test.done || true
echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
141 0 0
```

This is not ok:

```
seq 1 10000 | head | FOOBAR > test.done || true
echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
0
```