# snakemake rule calls a shell script but exits after first command

Tags: shell, for-loop, snakemake

I have a shell script that works well if I just run it from command line. When I call it from a rule within snakemake it fails.

The script runs a for loop over a file of identifiers and uses those to grep the sequences from a fastq file followed by multiple sequence alignment and makes a consensus.

Here is the script. I placed some echo statements in there and for some reason it doesn't call the commands. It stops at the grep statement.

I have tried adding set +o pipefail; in the rule but that doesn't work either.

```
 #!/bin/bash


function Usage(){
    echo -e "\
    Usage: $(basename $0) -r|--read2 -l|--umi-list -f|--outfile \n\ 
    where: ... \n\
    " >&2
        exit 1
}

# Check argument count
[[ "$#" -lt 2 ]] && Usage
# parse arguments
while [[ "$#" -gt 1 ]];do
    case "$1" in
        -r|--read2)
            READ2="$2"
            shift
            ;;
        -l|--umi-list)
            UMI="$2"
            shift
            ;;
        -f|--outfile)
            OUTFILE="$2"
            shift
            ;;
        *)
            Usage
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done

# Set defaults


# Check arguments
[[ -f "${READ2}" ]] || (echo "Cannot find input file ${READ2}, exiting..." >&2; exit 1)
[[ -f "${UMI}" ]] || (echo "Cannot find input file ${UMI}, exiting..." >&2; exit 1)

#Create output directory
OUTDIR=$(dirname "${OUTFILE}")
[[ -d "${OUTDIR}" ]] || (set -x; mkdir -p "${OUTDIR}")


# Make temporary directories
TEMP_DIR="${OUTDIR}/temp"
[[ -d "${TEMP_DIR}" ]] || (set -x; mkdir -p "${TEMP_DIR}")


#RUN consensus script

for f in $( more "${UMI}" | cut -f1);do
NAME=$(echo $f)
grep  "${NAME}" "${READ2}" | cut -f1 -d ' ' | sed 's/@M/M/' > "${TEMP_DIR}/${NAME}.name"
echo subsetting reads
seqtk  subseq "${READ2}" "${TEMP_DIR}/${NAME}.name" | seqtk  seq  -A > "${TEMP_DIR}/${NAME}.fasta"

~/software/muscle3.8.31_i86linux64  -msf -in "${TEMP_DIR}/${NAME}.fasta" -out "${TEMP_DIR}/${NAME}.muscle.fasta"

echo make consensus
~/software/EMBOSS-6.6.0/emboss/cons -sequence "${TEMP_DIR}/${NAME}.muscle.fasta" -outseq "${TEMP_DIR}/${NAME}.cons.fasta"

  sed -i 's/n//g' "${TEMP_DIR}/${NAME}.cons.fasta"
  sed -i "s/EMBOSS_001/${NAME}.cons/" "${TEMP_DIR}/${NAME}.cons.fasta"
done
cat "${TEMP_DIR}/*.cons.fasta" > "${OUTFILE}"
```

Snakemake rule:

```
rule make_consensus:
    input:
        r2=get_extracted,
        lst="{prefix}/{sample}/reads/cell_barcode_umi.count" 
    output:
        fasta="{prefix}/{sample}/reads/fasta/{sample}.R2.consensus.fa"
    shell:
        "sh ./scripts/make_consensus.sh -r {input.r2} -l {input.lst} -f {output.fasta}"
```

**Edit Snakemake error messages** I changed some of the paths to a neutral filepath

```
RuleException:
CalledProcessError in line 29 of ~/user/scripts/consensus.smk:
Command ' set -euo pipefail;  sh ./scripts/make_consensus.sh -r  ~/user/file.extracted.fastq -l ~/user/cell_barcode_umi
.count -f ~/user/file.consensus.fa ' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  File "~/user/scripts/consensus.smk", line 29, in __rule
_make_consensus
  File "~/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 56, in run
Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

If there are better ways to do this than using a shell for loop please let me know!

thanks!

**Edit**

Script ran as standalone: first grep

```
grep  AGGCCGTTCT_TGTGGATG R_extracted/wgs_5_OL_debug.R2.extracted.fastq | cut -f1 -d ' ' | sed 's/@M/M/' > ./fasta/temp/AGGCCGTTCT_TGTGGATG.name
```

Script ran through snakemake: first 2 grep statements

```
grep  :::::::::::::: R_extracted/wgs_5_OL_debug.R2.extracted.fastq | cut -f1 -d ' ' | sed 's/@M/M/' > ./fasta/temp/::::::::::::::.name
```

I'm now trying to figure out where those :::: in snakemake are coming from. All ideas welcome

Comment: What are the error messages?

Comment: It might be useful to include an example `snakemake` invocation.

Comment: What is the error that you get when using `set +o pipefail;` as part of your rule's shell command?

Answer (score 1):

> It stops at the grep statement

My guess is that the `grep` command in `make_consensus.sh` doesn't capture anything. `grep` returns exit code 1 in such cases and the non-zero exit status propagates to snakemake. (see also [Handling SIGPIPE error in snakemake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46569236/handling-sigpipe-error-in-snakemake))

Loosely related... There is an inconsistency between the shebang of `make_consensus.sh` that says the script should be executed with `bash` (`#!/bin/bash`) and the actual execution using sh (`sh ./scripts/make_consensus.sh`). (In practice it shouldn't make any difference since sh is probably redirected to bash anyway)

Comment: I look deeper into it. I'll add an edit with echo grep ... for snakemake and when the script is run as a stand alone script. The return different things for the first 2 elements in the for loop.