# snakemake returns a non-zero exit status on a simple rule when executing with --cluster

Tags: snakemake, pbs

The following snakemake rule fails when I execute it with `snakemake -r -p --jobs 40 --cluster "qsub"`

```
rule raven_assembly:
    """
    Assemble reads with Raven v1.5.0
    """
    input:
        "results/01_pooled_reads/eb_flongle_reads_pooled.fastq.gz"
    output:
        assembly="results/eb_raven_assembly.fasta",
    shell:
        """
        zcat {input} | head -n 2 > {output.assembly} 1> out.txt 2> errors.txt
        """
```

As you can probably tell the original rule was calling the software raven, but I've been simplifying the rule to investigate the source of the job failure.

The corresponding error message:

```
Error in rule raven_assembly:
    jobid: 1
    output: results/eb_raven_assembly.fasta
    shell:

        zcat results/01_pooled_reads/eb_flongle_reads_pooled.fastq.gz | head -n 2 > results/eb_raven_assembly.fasta &> errors.txt

        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)
    cluster_jobid: Your job 183238 ("snakejob.raven_assembly.1.sh") has been submitted

Error executing rule raven_assembly on cluster (jobid: 1, external: Your job 183238 ("snakejob.raven_assembly.1.sh") has been submitted, jobscript: /misc/scratch3/jmartijn/snakemake-test/.snakemake/tmp.95wb9rak/snakejob.raven_assembly.1.sh). For error details see the cluster log and the log files of the involved rule(s).
```

The `out.txt` file actually returns the expected zcat output, while the `errors.txt` is an empty file. If I run the zcat command manually, it works fine and returns an 0 exit status.

The jobscript disappears as soon as the snakemake workflow closes, but if I check it while it is still attempting to run it looks like this

```
#!/bin/sh
# properties = {"type": "single", "rule": "raven_assembly", "local": false, "input": ["results/01_pooled_reads/eb_flongle_reads_pooled.fastq.gz"], "output": ["results/eb_raven_assembly.fasta"], "wildcards": {}, "params": {}, "log": [], "threads": 1, "resources": {"mem_mb": 10903, "disk_mb": 10903, "tmpdir": "/tmp"}, "jobid": 1, "cluster": {}}
cd '/misc/scratch3/jmartijn/snakemake-test' && /scratch2/software/anaconda/envs/proj-ergo/bin/python3.7 -m snakemake --snakefile '/misc/scratch3/jmartijn/snakemake-test/Snakefile' 'results/eb_raven_assembly.fasta' --allowed-rules 'raven_assembly' --cores 'all' --attempt 1 --force-use-threads  --wait-for-files '/misc/scratch3/jmartijn/snakemake-test/.snakemake/tmp.ka4jh42u' 'results/01_pooled_reads/eb_flongle_reads_pooled.fastq.gz' --force --keep-target-files --keep-remote --max-inventory-time 0 --nocolor --notemp --no-hooks --nolock --ignore-incomplete --skip-script-cleanup  --conda-frontend 'mamba' --wrapper-prefix 'https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake-wrappers/raw/' --printshellcmds  --latency-wait 5 --scheduler 'ilp' --scheduler-solver-path '/scratch2/software/anaconda/envs/proj-ergo/bin' --default-resources 'mem_mb=max(2*input.size_mb, 1000)' 'disk_mb=max(2*input.size_mb, 1000)' 'tmpdir=system_tmpdir' --mode 2 && touch '/misc/scratch3/jmartijn/snakemake-test/.snakemake/tmp.ka4jh42u/1.jobfinished' || (touch '/misc/scratch3/jmartijn/snakemake-test/.snakemake/tmp.ka4jh42u/1.jobfailed'; exit 1)
```

The computer cluster is running SGE 8.1.9 and has Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as OS. Snakemake version 7.8.0

Comment: `head` is the likely cause. See this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46569236/3998252).

Comment: You are right. I had replaced my raven (another software) call with a simpler bash command, but apparently it wasn't as simple as that because of the pipe. If I replaced it with `touch {output.assembly}` it worked OK.

In any case, my original problem was apparently that the $PATH wasn't passed on to the job. Simple bash commands worked, but raven wasn't in the $PATH in the job. The solution was to add the -V flag in the qsub command.